# singleton for returning next number in a sequence for rails webservice controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-services, singleton

I've implemented a datanoise based Rails 2.3.5 SOAP webservice. the single webservice api controller would be servicing multiple requests - data which needs to be stored in the mysql db. For the transaction reference I need to use the next in sequence of 5 digit hexadecimal number which gets initialized with the max number from the database when the rails app is started so that I always start with the last number in the hex sequence. What is the easiest and practical way to implement this? A singleton class (model?) or cache/session?

Answer (score 0):

You may just want a helper method.  If you're already in a class, perhaps a protected method?  But the code is pretty simple, so depending on what you're doing you might just use it directly:

```
(hex_string.to_i(16) + 1).to_s(16)
```

That way it's clear what's going on

Comment: I have one webservice controller class that would get invoked concurrently for each client requesting the webservice api access. These instances would simultaneously request the next number in the sequence for them to use to store their transaction to mysql. So it would need to be aware of multiple invocations of the controller class.

Would I need to create a class in the models directory or under RAILS lib? I need to initialize the hex string at start of the rails server to the max hex value sequence in the database.